# Real numbers multiplication

Tags: fortran

I have a code which includes some multiplication events of real numbers and I always get the answer zero for that particular subroutine, regardless of the input variables.

All variables are `real*4` type declared and have values like e.g. a=5, b=3.5 & c=0.0005.

I am using Plato IDE

`

```
Subroutine Load_Modulation_100()

Real*4  ::  Te      
Real*4  ::  Ee      
Real*4  ::  Et      
Real*4  ::  QLHV    
Real*4  ::  mfg     
Real*4  ::  Qfeul   
Real*4  ::  mf      
Real*4  ::  Pe      
Real*4  ::  Pt

Te      =   100  
Ee      =   28.2  
mf      =   0.0005  
QLHV    =   47141  
Et      =   66.8    
Cpfg    =   4.5  

            Qfeul = (mf * QLHV)
            Pe = (Qfeul * (Ee / 100))
            Pt = (Qfeul * (Et / 100))

Write (*,*) Pe, 'kW'  
Write (*,*) Pt, 'kW'  

End Subroutine Load_Modulation_100`
```

Comment: I have updated my question with respective subroutine sample.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with `gfortran` -- maybe Plato-specific?

Comment: I could imagine getting 0 if some of the variables was undeclared, but in your example it is not the case.

Comment: Pleas check you are compiling **Exactly** the same code you are showing. Use `IMPLICIT NONE`, it is really important.

Comment: This is the error I get: "Source Code.F95(190) : comment 368 - This assignment will result in a loss of precision, assigning from REAL(KIND=1) to INTEGER(KIND=3)" Line 190 has this value: "mf =0.0003935"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the case, but integer truncation can be a problem...
I would be more explicit and maybe use some debug.

```
Subroutine Load_Modulation_100()
IMPLICIT NONE 
Real*4  ::  Te      
Real*4  ::  Ee      
Real*4, PARAMETER  ::  Et = 66.8E0
Real*4  ::  QLHV    
Real*4  ::  mfg     
Real*4  ::  Qfeul   
Real*4  ::  mf      
Real*4  ::  Pe      
Real*4  ::  Pt
LOGICAL*4  ::  IO = .TRUE.

! Te      =   100  ! This is a float, it just does;t jump off the page as one
Te      =   100.0E0  !
Ee      =   28.2  
mf      =   0.0005  
QLHV    =   47141  ! This is a float, it just does't jump off the page as one
!Moved to parameter Et      =   66.8    
Cpfg    =   4.5  

     IF(IO) WRITE(*,*)' (Ee / 100)=', (Ee / 100)
        Qfeul = (mf * QLHV)
!        Pe = (Qfeul * (Ee / 100))
        Pe = (Qfeul * (Ee / FLOAT(100)))
!        Pt = (Qfeul * (Et / 100))
        Pt = (Qfeul * (Et / 100.0E0))

Write (*,*) Pe, 'kW'  
Write (*,*) Pt, 'kW'  

RETURN
End Subroutine Load_Modulation_100!`
```

Comment: I was thinking along these lines. But Te does not have to be defined as `100.0`, just `100` is fine. But if Ee or Et was nor properky declared as `real `, that would be a big problem.

Comment: Is it necessary to declare the variables inside the Subroutine being used;  Can't we use the variables from the previous subroutine without declaring them again in the current subroutine?

Comment: @ArslanYousaf No, you cannot. You must use modules. And you **must** show the **exact** code you are running next time in your questions.

Comment: @VladimirF The subroutine I posted is actually the part of my code. I am not sure if I can post the whole code here..

Comment: @ArslanYousaf Don't lie. From the error message it is clear that `mf` is integer in your code (`Source Code.F95 line 190`). That is also the point of this answer.

Comment: @VladimirF No!! You understood it wrong! It's a real based variable in my code and you are considering the error message details of changing this real to integer type. If you want I can show you my complete code again. It's better to verify first, before declaring someone else guilty!!

Comment: @ArslanYousaf No, I don't believe your interpretation that message. It is assignment TO integer.

Comment: There were float conversions in my example. You may want to try that??